# Generics: money VS some money

Tags: grammar, terminology

Here is a definition of generics, given by C.Lyons in "Definiteness" (1999):

"**Generic noun phrases** are those in which reference is made to an entire class, or, perhaps more accurately, which are used to express **generalizations about a class as a whole*** – the class in question being that consisting of all the entities satisfying the description inherent in the noun or nominal".

Now look at the following examples:

(1) There was some money in the jar;

(2) There was money in the jar;

In his article for the journal "Linguistic Inquiery (Vol.14, No,1 , Winter, 1983)", Erich Woisetschlaeger mentions Robert Fiengo, who treats "*money*" in (2) as generic:

"Fiengo (1974) is surely right in treating *some money* as having specific reference, and *money* as having generic reference".

I fail to see how *money* in (2) is *a generalization about a class as a whole*, rather it is a reference to a certain quantity of something, that fits the description of *money*:

- *There was some money in the jar* --> there was something that fits the description of *money* (not all money);

  My question is:

Does a generic reference include this idea of "something that fits the description" (and Lyons just happens not to state it explicitly) or are Woisetschlaeger and Fiengo plain wrong?

Comment: This is probably yet another question where different precising definitions are used by different linguists. One can see (1) as being a distantish relative of 'I saw some coins in the jar', inviting 'How many coins were there?'  say. There _is_ more definiteness about the remark than is the case in (2): 'There was money in the jar; I caught the gleam of gold.' (Pirate-time setting). (2) is less likely to invite 'How many coins?' // That having been said, I'm having trouble seeing either as warranting 'specifying' classification. Masters puts 'some' as more indefinite than 'a' (though ...

Comment: admittedly he has the zero article (as in (2)) as the most indefinite). If one uses a broader definition of 'generic' to mean 'non-specifying' (and I'm sure one can be found in some article or other), I'd say both (1) and (2) here merit the descriptor.

Comment: In my mind, (2) is generic because it uses money as a generalization about a class as a whole, and just says there was money, as opposed to milk, dirt, beads, nails, etc.

Comment: There's a literature on the subject; consult Pelletier (ed), _Kinds, Things, and Stuff_ (Oxford 2010) for a selection of topics. In English, there are [three main types of generic noun phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html), marked by articles and number inflection.

Comment: Edwin, Jim, John, thanks for your contributions! John, Lyons explains the same 3 types of "generic NPs" in great detail, but the problem persists, as generic utterences (rather than generic NPs), regardless of the type, involve Generalisation about the whole class of things. The example given by Woisetschlaeger doesn't seem to be about generalisation (if by generalisation we imply making general statements about whole class of things, which is not the case here, because it isn't money that the speaker is talking about).

Comment: "Money is an item accepted as a payment for goods and services" - this is a generalisation about money (about ALL MONEY, that is). Money here is generic. "There was money in that jar" - this is not a generalisation about anything, nor are ALL MONEY in the world spoken of. A new question is: is generalisation about THE WHOLE CLASS of things (regardless of what of the tree type of generics it belongs to) a necessary requirement for a generic interpretation of an NP?

Comment: According to Lyons, it is not the NPs that are generics but the utterences (green coke bottles with an "x" label on them sell better than plastic ones". Another example: "An Indian smokes a pipe every night" - this sentence has three readings to it, and one of them is generic". To me, what makes a generic a generic is the generalisation made about it (this is, when the generic is in the TOPIC, not in the COMMENT). What are your ideas?